# If a function always has the same value as its second derivative prove it can't be normalized.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Say we have a function such that,

$d^2\psi/dx^2\ge K\psi $ for some $K\in \Bbb R,  K>0$,

show that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi(x)^2dx=0, \infty$$

Anyone have an proof? It would be helpful.

Comment: Do you mean that the integral gives $0$ *or* $\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true.  Consider e.g. $f(x) = \dfrac{-1}{1+x^2}$.  Note that   $f''(x) \ge 2 f(x)$ everywhere, but $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)^2\ dx = \pi/2$.

It would be true for functions that are somewhere positive (because such a function is convex on the interval where it is positive).